# Событие onclick="document.... Вставлять в текст и/или обрамлять выделенное

Tags: javascript

```
<input id="strk" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('pbody').value+='[S][/S]'; return false;" value = " S " />
```

[image: ,,,]

Я понимаю что **+**

```
.value+='[S][/S]'
```

вставляет текст (ВВ-код) в конец текста. А как сделать чтобы вставка происходила в текущей позиции курсора?

Как сделать чтобы вставка "обрамляла" выделенный текст в форме?

---

Подробнее: При написании текста в форме пользователь кликает на кнопке и нужно:

1. вставлять ВВ-код в текй позицию курсора
2. если пользователь выделил текст для заключения его в ВВ-код, нужно вставить начало ВВкода - перед выделенным тькстом, конец ВВкода - в конец выделенного текста. То есть вставить выделенный текст в ВВ код.

1 и 2 нужно не в одном решении сделать (мне так проще для понимания).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой нехитрый скрипт. Я внутри расписал для вас всё комментариями.

```js
function ShowSelection(bb) {
  var textComponent = document.getElementById('text');
  var selectedText;
  if(textComponent.selectionStart != undefined) {
    var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart; // Положение начала выделения
    var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd; // Положение конца выделения
  };
  if(startPos == endPos){ // Если текст не выделен (т.е. начальное и конечное положение равны)
    /* Берём текст от начала до начала положения курсора, добавляем BB тег, добавляем текст от конца положения курсора до конца строки */
    var val = textComponent.value.substring(0, startPos) + '['+bb+'][/'+bb+']' + textComponent.value.substring(endPos, textComponent.value.length);
    textComponent.value = val;
    
    // Устанавливаем выделение
    textComponent.focus(); 
    textComponent.setSelectionRange(startPos, endPos + (bb.length * 2) + 5); // В конце учитываем два содержимого BB и дополнительные символы [] и [/]
  }else{
    /* Берём текст от начала до начала веделния, добавляем BB тег, вставляем выделенный текст, добавляем закрытие BB, добавляем текст от конца выделения до конца строки */
    var val = textComponent.value.substring(0, startPos) + '['+bb+']'+textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)+'[/'+bb+']' + textComponent.value.substring(endPos, textComponent.value.length);
    textComponent.value = val;
    
    // Устанавливаем выделение
    textComponent.focus(); 
    textComponent.setSelectionRange(startPos, endPos + (bb.length * 2) + 5); // В конце учитываем два содержимого BB и дополнительные символы [] и [/]
  };
}
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    ShowSelection($(this).attr('data-bb'));
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {width: 300px;height: 140px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <button data-bb="b">Жирный</button>
  <button data-bb="i">Курсивый</button>
</p>
<textarea id="text">Не отведать ли вам чаю?</textarea>
```

Comment: "я нечто такое предполагал, но не думал, что это будет настолько ужасное" (H j Simpson +моя редакция). Просто копипастить и подставлять свои имена я не буду. @Yuri, порекомендуйте хорошую  бумажную книгу по js.

Comment: @root_xPovierennyy, к сожалению, с книгами не ко мне) Но ответ не ужасен, всё довольно просто выглядит, если разобраться